# Deleting TableView Rows With edit/delete button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying  to delete rows in my array, From a hit on the delete button, after having hit the edit, then the red minus little button. When I hit on the simulator the delete button nothing is happening. If someone could help me please.
Here is my code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    //here is where the magic doesn't happens
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [stories removeObjectAtIndex: storyIndex];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"module"];

    // clean up the link - get rid of spaces, returns, and tabs...
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"link: %@", storyLink);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
}
```

Comment: `[tableView beginUpdates]; ... [tableView endUpdates];`.

Comment: [tableView reload]; ?

Comment: Could you please edit an answer so i can rate the good answer so it could help other people after me please. I will try as you say Kevin, also iphonic :). Thanks for the answer:D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the follow..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    //here is where the magic doesn't happens
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [stories removeObjectAtIndex: storyIndex];

        //EDIT
        [tableView beginUpdates]; 
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [tableView endUpdates];

    }else{ //EDIT

         NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"module"];

        // clean up the link - get rid of spaces, returns, and tabs...
        storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
        storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];

        NSLog(@"link: %@", storyLink);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Its better with proper alignments and blocks.

Comment: i just implemented that, and it gets me a SIGABRT :§

Comment: it appears that i got a problem with "commitEditingStyle..." when i put this in the method scope the program don't go anymore in the method :§. Anyway thank you for the answer iphonic :).